# Как выровнять текст по центру? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #fff;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}


/* Container
===================*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
===================*/

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 35px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Intro
===================*/

.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 750px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: url("img/intro.jpg") #31344e center no-repeat;
}

.intro__title {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro__inner {
  max-width: 970px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400i|Open+Sans:700|Raleway:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Мой сайт</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <img src="img/ActiveBoxlogo.png" alt="">
        </div>


        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Our Team</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Download</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="conteiner">
      <div class="intro__inner">
        <h1 class="intro__title">Your Favorite One Page Multi Purpose Template</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Вот как должно получиться]

Answer (score 0):

Убрать у .intro flex-direction: column и задать align-items: center

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c7279;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #fff;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}


/* Container
===================*/

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header
===================*/

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 35px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #515369;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Intro
===================*/

.intro {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 750px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: url("img/intro.jpg") #31344e center no-repeat;
}

.intro__title {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.intro__inner {
  max-width: 970px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo:400i|Open+Sans:700|Raleway:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <img src="img/ActiveBoxlogo.png" alt="">
        </div>


        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Our Team</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
          <a class="nav__link" href="#">Download</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="intro">
    <div class="conteiner">
      <div class="intro__inner">
        <h1 class="intro__title">Your Favorite One Page Multi Purpose Template</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: не видел, что вы тоже дали ответ, не было намерения выдавать ваш ответ за свой. Не принимайте на личный счет